# Передать значение в бд - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, asp.net

Есть форма Catalog
В Catalog.aspx есть DataList с элементом Label2.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [CatId], [Name], [Price], [Description], [Image] FROM [Products]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Item">
            <div class="name">
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
            </div>
            <div>
                Код:<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
            </div>
            <img src="<%# Eval("Image") %>" height="115" alt="item"/>
            <div class="price">
                Цена:

                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price")%>' />p.
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
                    onclick="Button2_Click" Text="В КОРЗИНУ" />
            </div>
            <div class="desc">
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />  
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

В Catalog.aspx.cs передаю данные в бд

```
sqlCon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cart(ClientId,ProductId,Amount) VALUES (@ClientId,@ProductId,@Amount)", sqlCon);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ClientId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Label2.Text;
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 1;

cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Подчёркивает Label2 в Catalog.aspx.cs, пишет что он не существует. Как мне передать значение из Label2 (Id из таблицы Products)?

Comment: Какому классу принадлежит метод с `cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();`? Метод объекта или статический? У Вас, что, поле "Amount" строковое?

Comment: Amount с типом int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label2` подчеркивается, потому что такого элемента действительно нет.
Вы используете `asp:DataList` которому задаете `ItemTemplate` - это значит, что элементы описанные внутри темплейта, создаются и, соответственно, доступны после привязки данных.

Теперь по коду: подозреваю, что код

```
sqlCon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd_SQL = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cart(ClientId,ProductId,Amount) VALUES (@ClientId,@ProductId,@Amount)", sqlCon);
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ClientId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =Label2.Text;
cmd_SQL.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 1;

cmd_SQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd_SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Находится в обработчике `Button2_Click` и вызывается здесь

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="В КОРЗИНУ" />
```

В таком случае обработчик принимает в качестве параметра *sender* кнопку по которой нажали

ее можно получить: `var btn = (Button)sender;`

Далее, у веб контролов есть поле `Parent` в данном случае он указывает на объект [DataListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitem(v=vs.110).aspx). Это контейнер в котором находятся контролы из разметки `ItemTemplate`. Осталось только найти нужный элемент с помощью метода [`FindControls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Все вместе будет:

```
var btn = (Button)sender;
var dli = (DataListItem)btn.Parent;
var Label2 = (Label)dli.FindControl('Label2');
```

или в одну строчку

```
var Label2 = (Label)(((DataListItem)((Button)sender).Parent).FindControl("Label2"));
```